# Shorthand notation for comparing composite keys (in PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, postgresql-9.5

I have two tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE a (a1 TEXT, a2 INTEGER, a3 INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (a2, a3));
CREATE TABLE b (b1 TEXT, b2 INTEGER, b3 INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (b2, b3) REFERENCES a);
```

I would like to obtain `a1` for those rows in `a` that are referenced by at least one row in `b`. E.g. like so:

```
SELECT a1 FROM a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE a.a2 = b.b2 AND a.a3 = b.b3);
```

Is there a shorter (and efficient) way to express this, preferably one that would not require me to list all columns in composite keys explicitly, for that list may change?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do that in a single query when the columns have different names.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What could be done if the column names would match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One short-cut you can do in Postgres is:

```
SELECT a1
FROM a
WHERE (a.a2, a.a3) IN (SELECT b.b2, b.b3 FROM b) ;
```

Of course, you still have to list the keys.

If `b` has no duplicates *and* if the column names were the same, you could do:

```
SELECT a1
FROM a JOIN
     b
     USING (a2, a3);
```

With `USING`, you only have to list the keys once.

I hesitate to say this, but you could also further reduce this using `NATURAL JOIN`, assuming that the common keys have the same name *and no other columns have the same name*:

```
SELECT a1
FROM a NATURAL JOIN
     b;
```

However, I *strongly* discourage the use of `NATURAL JOIN` because it uses all columns in the two tables that have the same name.  It doesn't respect declared foreign key relationships, so it can return unexpected results.

Comment: Excellent. Also agreed: I would not use `NATURAL JOIN` under these circumstances.

Comment: Excellent but do not agree that `NATURAL JOIN` should be discouraged. I mean, inner join doesn't "respect declared foreign key relationships" either. That said, if I had `NATURAL JOIN` in SQL Server I probably would avoid all other join types!

Comment: @onedaywhen . . . Inner join does not "arbitrarily" choose unseen columns for the join conditions.  `NATURAL JOIN` is extremely dangerous and never should have been added into the language with the existing semantics.

Comment: Such different ways of seeing things! As regards arbitrariness, `INNER JOIN` allows me to join tables on arbitrary conditions not necessarily involving those tables (e.g. `1 = 1`), whereas `NATURAL JOIN` solely uses common column names. As regards danger, the life critical systems I work on use a variety of processes to ensure safety (including consistent attribute naming across all schema and automated SQL unit/system tests). I'm certain being able to use `NATURAL JOIN` would *reduce* our risk. YMMV.

Comment: @onedaywhen . . . There is no arbitrariness.  `USING` and `ON` require that the query *explicitly* list the columns being joined.  This is safe and explicit.  If someone makes an error, then it is there, in the query.  `NATURAL JOIN` depends on the construct of the table, something that is not visible to the query.  Hence, it is unsafe and can result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: You omitted the word 'expression' from 'table expression' ("`NATURAL JOIN` depends on the table expressions involved" is absolutely correct). Whether the table expression is 'visible' in the query does rather depend on the query, doesn't it? You seem to looking for problems that may not exist e.g. a user is writing a query involving a base/viewed table where they don't know the names of all the columns? If you want to make explicit the column names in the query, and you like using `USING` in a join, then you could fix this 'problem' by using a CTE,